# Android;manage UI controls according RBAC

Tags: android, user-interface, design-patterns, rbac

In a project I have 3 Actors and 5 Use cases.I want to regulate Actors access to entities based on their roles(RBAC).Also all Actors see the same UI,but some UI controls are disabled for each actor according to his/her Role.I can use If statements to decide specific control must be enabled for current Actor or disabled? For example:

```
If (User.Roles(...)) 
{
    btnEditOrder.enabled = false;
}
```

That is possible,but UI is complex and each layout has many UI controls.So managing all these possible options and hard-code that logic in the application seems daunting.Specially, number of use cases,actors and their permissions may change later.Do you know how I can avoid hard-code such logic and have a good design?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO it would be good to create separate menu.xml files for each role.

Let's say you make separate menu.xml files namely:

1. `options_menu_manager.xml`
2. `options_menu_engineer.xml`
3. `options_menu_director.xml`

You will need to make a Helper class around it. I am assuming you have the role already in the memory, you can do something like:

```
class Helper{

    public static int getOptionsMenu(){
        switch(Global.role){
            case Constants.MANAGER:
                return R.menu.options_menu_manager.xml;
            ...
            ...     
        }
    }
}
```

and wherever you need to get the menus, you can use a helper function instead of using a R.menu.* file.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(Helper.getOptionsMenu(), menu);
    return true;
}
```

Although, this is just a way of getting ROLE based menu. You should still have a good background validation of the authorization of all the performed actions. For that also you can create a helper that matches the current user's role against the allowed actions to see if he is allowed to do what he is doing or not.